# I want to get last date of the month and add n months to it but calendar instance is taking only 30 days in Java

Tags: java, datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calender.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
int months = 1;
calender.add(Calendar.MONTH, months );
String time = sdf .format(calender .getTime());
System.out.println(time);
```

Since current month is April and last date is 2020-04-30
Next month last date I should get 2020-05-31
but I am getting last date as 2020-05-30

Any thing am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. It’s much nicer to work with than the old classes `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
    LocalDate endOfNextMonth = 
            YearMonth                            // Represent an entire month in a particular year.
            .now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Volgograd"))  // Capture the current year-month as seen in a particular time zone. Returns a `YearMonth` object.
            .plusMonths(1)                       // Move to the next month. Returns another `YearMonth` object.
            .atEndOfMonth();                     // Determine the last day of that year-month. Returns a `LocalDate` object.

    String time = endOfNextMonth.toString();     // Represent the content of the `LocalDate` object by generating text in standard ISO 8601 format.

    System.out.println("Last day of next month: " + time);
```

Output when running today:

> Last day of next month: 2020-05-31

A `YearMonth`, as the name maybe says, is a year and month without day of month. It has an `atEndOfMonth` method that conveniently gives us the last day of the month as a `LocalDate`. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so what we need here. And its `toString` method conveniently gives the format that you wanted (it’s ISO 8601).

Depending on the reason why you want the last day of another month there are a couple of other approaches you may consider. If you need to handle date ranges that always start and end on month boundaries, you may either:

1. Represent your range as a range of `YearMonth` objects. Would this free you from knowing the last day of the month altogether?
2. Represent the end of your range as the first of the following month *exclusive*. Doing math on the 1st of each month is simpler since it is always day 1 regardless of the length of the month.

### What went wrong in your code?

No matter if using `Calendar`, `LocalDate` or some other class you need to do things in the opposite order: first add one month, then find the end of the month. As you know, months have different lengths, so the important part is getting the end *of that month where you want to get the last day*. Putting it the other way: setting either a `LocalDate` or a `Calendar` to the last day of the month correctly sets it to the last day of the month in qustion but *does not* instruct it to stay at the last day of the month after subsequent changes to its value, such as adding a month. If you add a month to April 29, you get May 29. If you add a month to April 30, you get May 30. Here it doesn’t matter that 30 is the last day of April while 30 is not the last day of May.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use `LocalDate` like this:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate lastDay = now.withDayOfMonth(now.lengthOfMonth());
LocalDate nextMonth = lastDay.plusMonths(1);
```

Comment: Using java.time is a very good idea. Your code still gives `2020-05-30`, though, not `2020-05-31`, so you are not really answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use deprecated classes from `java.util.*`.

Use classes from `java.time.*`.

Example with `LocalDate` :

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
      LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
      int months = 1;
      date = date.plusMonths(months);
      date = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());
      System.out.println(date.format(dateTimeFormatter));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
2020-05-31
```

Example with `Calendar` :

```
 public class Testing {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        int months = 1;
        calender.add(Calendar.MONTH, months);
        calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calender.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String time = sdf.format(calender.getTime());
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
 2020-05-31
```